# Ansible Mount multiple disk in a server

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, mount

I have the code below that maps a single disk in a server to a mount point. However, on my servers, I have 5 disks and I want to add these disks to the same playbook without having to do it one by one.

```yaml
- hosts: ip_of_host
  vars:
    disk_dev: "/dev/sdb"
    mount_path: "/mnt/daily_backup"
  gather_facts: true
  become: true # Get root privileges
  tasks:
    - name: Use entire disk
      community.general.parted:
        device: "{{ disk_dev }}"
        number: 1
        name: data
        state: present
        label: gpt
        unit: MiB
        part_start: 0%
        part_end: 100%

    - name: Define ext file system for the disk
      community.general.filesystem:
        fstype: ext4
        dev: "{{ disk_dev }}1"

    - name: Create the mount directory
      ansible.builtin.file:
        path: "{{ mount_path }}"
        state: directory
        mode: '0755'

    - name: Perform the mounting on the mount device
      ansible.builtin.mount:
        fstype: ext4
        src: "{{ disk_dev }}1"
        path: "{{ mount_path }}"
        state: mounted
```

So how can I add more disks let's say `/dev/sdc`, `/dev/sdd`, `/dev/sde` to the above script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible solution. This is mainly a pseudo example. Actually calling the modules was not tested so you may have to adapt some params. But you should get the general idea.

*Note if needed: in the below example [`d` is an alias to `default`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.default)*

Create a file `mount_disk_each.yml` where you place your individual tasks with some refactoring:

```yaml
- name: Use entire disk
  community.general.parted:
    device: "{{ disk.dev }}"
    number: "{{ disk.part_number | d(1) }}"
    name: "{{ disk.name }}"
    state: present
    label: "{{ disk.label | d('gpt') }}"
    unit: "{{ disk.unit | d('MiB') }}"
    part_start: "{{ disk.start | d('0%') }}"
    part_end: "{{ dist.end | d('100%') }}"

- name: Define ext file system for the disk
  community.general.filesystem:
    fstype: "{{ disk.fstype | d('ext4') }}"
    dev: "{{ disk.dev }}{{ disk.part_number | d(1) }}"

- name: Create the mount directory
  ansible.builtin.file:
    path: "{{ disk.mount_path }}"
    state: directory
    mode: '0755'

- name: Perform the mounting on the mount device
  ansible.builtin.mount:
    fstype: "{{ disk.fstype | d('ext4') }}"
    src: "{{ disk.dev }}{{ disk.part_number | d(1) }}"
    path: "{{ disk.mount_path }}"
    state: mounted
```

Then call that file in a loop from your main playbook passing the correct info for each device.

Notes:

- I targeted localhost just for the example but you can of course target any host/group
- If you have multiple host with different disks, you can declare the `disks` var for each host in your inventory instead of the below play var. See [How to build your inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html)

```yaml
- name: mount needed disks
  hosts: localhost

  vars:
    disks:
      - dev: /dev/sda
        name: data
        mount_path: /usr/var/data
      - dev: /dev/sdb
        name: cache
        label: <some_other_label>
        unit: GiB
        part_end: 50%
        fstype: xfs
        mount_path: /usr/var/cache
      - dev: /dev/sdb
        part_number: 2
        name: backup
        part_start: 50%
        part_end: 100%
        mount_path: /usr/var/backup
  
  tasks:
    - name: Create and mount each partition
      ansible.builtin.include_tasks: mount_disk_each.yml
      loop: "{{ disks }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: disk
```

Comment: Almost solves the problem, I it stops at the last step of the procedure which I suspect is not an ansible issue but a mounting issue. I get the following error "wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/nvme0n1p1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.\n". As far as I can tell, I am mounting ext4 filesystem and I have tried this manually which works.

Answer (score 1):

one of the ways to achieve is through having a list of dictionaries and iterating through them:

```
  vars:
    disks:
      - disk_dev: "/dev/sdb"
        mount_path: "/mnt/daily_backup"
      - disk_dev: "/dev/sdc"
        mount_path: "/mnt/mount_seconddisk"
```

and then:

```
    - name: Perform the mounting on the mount device
      ansible.builtin.mount:
        fstype: ext4
        src: "{{ item.disk_dev }}"
        path: "{{ item.mount_path }}"
        state: mounted
      loop: "{{ disks }}"
```